# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'source' property in

Tags: php, soap, soapfault

I am trying to connect osticket support system with opencart.
I tried to integrate with this [SOAP](http://www.cyberde.nl/software-en-US/osticket-soap-mod/)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$osticket = new SoapClient('http://www.website.com/osticket/api/soap/index.php?wsdl');

// Set up the parameters
$args = array(
    'username'      => 'WebService',
    'password'      => 'MySecr3tp@ssword',
    'origin'        => 'Web',
    'alertUser'     => true,
    'alertStaff'    => true,
    'ticketData'    => array(
        'name'      => utf8_encode('sir Test'),
        'email'     => utf8_encode('some@email.com'),
        'subject'   => utf8_encode('testing'),
        'message'   => utf8_encode('this is a message'),
        'topicId'   => 3, //topic Website Support
        'deptId'    => 2, //department Sales
        'staffId'   => null,
        'duedate'   => null,
        'time'      => null,
        'pri'       => 2, // default priority
        'phone'     => null,
    )
);

try {
    // Send the request and receive the ticketID
    $result = $osticket->__call('ostTicket.open',$args);
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    throw $e;
}
?>
```

The error I get is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'source' property in /home/website/website.com/catalog/view/theme/testtheme/template/information/contact.tpl:60 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/website/website.com/catalog/view/theme/testtheme/template/information/contact.tpl(60): SoapClient->__call('ostTicket.open', Array) 
#1 /home/website/website.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php(67): require('/home/website/tu...') 
#2 /home/website/website.com/catalog/controller/information/contact.php(127): Controller->render() 
#3 /home/website/website.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_front.php(43): ControllerInformationContact->index() 
#4 /home/website/website.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_front.php(29): Front->execute(Array, Array) 
#5 /home/website/website.com/index.php(238): Front->dispatch(Object(Action)) 
#6 {main} thrown in/home/website/website.com/catalog/view/theme/testtheme/template/information/contact.tpl on line 60
```

Here is the line 60 (`/template/information/contact.tpl`):

```
$result = $osticket->__call('ostTicket.open',$args);
```

I'd be grateful if anyone kindly help me in this issue.

SOAP Info

This is from phpinfo

```
Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400
```

Comment: What about sharing Your `Soap` implementation? Without any code provided we are unable to help. Also post the whole error (also with the file listing). Anyway this has almost nothing to do with OpenCart thus consider removing of `Opencart` tag...

Comment: Hi, Updated with info, thanks for the fast reply

Comment: Hmm, the exception is saying that some object is missing a **`source`** property it has to have, but I dunno which object it is pointing to. Maybe it could also be this `$args` array...

Comment: Do I have to provide "real" login credentials in the array? currently it doesn't have such...

Comment: Nope, You do not have to provide the real login credentials here, but I suppose You use the real ones in Your code when connecting to the SOAP service, right?

Comment: yes, I gave real ones there...

Comment: And are You connecting to a real URL (I mean not to the `website.com`)? Are those `topic ID`, `department ID`, `priority` present within the ticket application? I am just guessing as Your code is the same as in the documentation. Nevermind, **I would rather contact their support then asking here...**

Answer (score 4):

I'm also having same problem, and I've been searching the web and found no answer.  So, I traced it myself.  And I loved to share how I fixed it.

As you can see on the http://www.website.com/osticket/api/soap/index.php?wsdl (change it to your URL)

under the ( xsd:complexType name="TicketData" ),which parameters needed for ostTicket.open

you can see that there's an element (xsd:element name="source" type="xsd:string") named source, so that's what is missing on the ticketData array.  Just **add that inside your ticketData array**, can be assigned w/ null.

ex. **'source'  => null,**

This solved my problem.  Hope it helps.